# Separating the code into a function and calling it doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This works perfectly fine. Now, I would like to incorporate this into a function and just call the function within my expression. It doesn't work.

**Working code:**

```
 render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.list.map(function(listValue){
            return <p>{listValue}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<List list={[1,2,3,4,5]} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**code with the function (doesn't work):**

```
   var List = React.createClass({
    addText: function()
    {
         this.props.list.map(function(listValue){
            return <p>{listValue}</p>;
        });
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
         {this.addText()}
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<List list={[1,2,3,4,5]} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: you aren't returning the mapped list, try adding a `return` infront of `this.props.list.map(...`

Comment: OMG, I can't believe what I've missed here, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've extracted the call to `map` into another function and *maybe* assumed the `return` call inside it was sufficient to return the result of the whole call (it just returns the mapped value for that iteration of map).

You just need to return the result of your map in your `addText` function:

```
var List = React.createClass({
    addText: function()
    {
        return (  // <------ADD THIS
           this.props.list.map(function(listValue){
            return <p>{listValue}</p>;
          })
        );  //<<-----DON'T FORGET TO CLOSE OFF THE NEW BRACKET
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
         {this.addText()}
        </div>
      )
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tnx **@Thomas altmann**, I forgot to make another return prior to my first return

```
var List = React.createClass({
    addText: function()
    {
         return (this.props.list.map(function(listValue){
            return <p>{listValue}</p>;
        })
         );
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
         {this.addText()}
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<List list={[1,2,3,4,5]} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```